# second order system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

How do i solve this system of equations? Or what is the method for solving these called?
$$y''=z' \cdot A$$
$$z''=-y' \cdot A + B$$
$y=y(t),z=z(t) \,A,B$ - constants. Derivatives by time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: this is a first-order system for $y'$ and $z'$.  Solve, then integrate.